# What's wrong with my Cython?

Tags: cython

I tried to write a Cython wrapper around the C++ library http://primesieve.org/

It wraps a single function `count`. So far, it installs correctly `python setup.py install`, but when I `import primesieve` the function `primesieve.count` is missing. Any ideas?

---

primesieve.pxd (following http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html)

```
cdef extern from "stdint.h":
    ctypedef unsigned long long uint64_t

cdef extern from "primesieve/include/primesieve.h":
    uint64_t primesieve_count_primes(uint64_t start, uint64_t stop)
```

primesieve.pyx

```
cimport primesieve

cpdef int count(self, int n):
    return primesieve.primesieve_count_primes(1, n)
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("*", ["primesieve.pyx"], include_dirs = ["primesieve/include"])])
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `setup.py` to link against `libprimesieve.so` by adding `libraries = ["primesieve"]` to you arguments to the `Extension` constructor.  Without it, you'll get this error:

```
ImportError: ./primesieve.so: undefined symbol: primesieve_count_primes
```

Once I changed `setup.py`, it worked for me:

```
$ python2 setup.py build
...
$ (cd build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 && python2 -c 'import primesieve; print primesieve.count(None, 5)')
3
```

Comment: Aha, thanks. Where is the documentation for `setuptools.Extension`?

Comment: Cool I also fixed an error `/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -lprimesieve` by installing the library `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install` and adding `library_dirs = ["/home/colonelpanic/lib"]` to Extension in setup.py . Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: Doesn't feel right to put absolute path to my home folder in there

Comment: Opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220762/how-to-build-library-without-sudo