# How to build library without sudo?

Tags: ld, travis-ci, configure

I usually build my library `./configure && make && sudo make install`. However the Travis docs discourage using sudo http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/

So I changed the build command to `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`. This worked, however at the next step (building a Python extension) I got an error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprimesieve

Any ideas? Do I need to add `$HOME/lib` to some environment variables, because I changed prefix?

1. My travis config https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python/blob/travis-ci/.travis.yml
2. Build log with error https://travis-ci.org/hickford/primesieve-python/jobs/69536543#L382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is like `PATH` for libraries. For example:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= $HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

More detailed information about library path variables is [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Environment variables that specifically influence how the *configure* script passes arguments to compilation are *LIBS* and *LD_FLAGS*. `bash ./configure --help` mentions these.

And as you mention in the comments `LIBRARY_PATH` also needs to be set. See [LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: Thanks. I also had to update `LIBRARY_PATH` as well as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, it is expected. Sorry for the omission.