# locate finds library but ldconfig does not

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am using using Centos 6.6 and there is a shared library the build generates used by number of executable and any executable using this shared library cannot find it as seen by ldd.
I can locate the library:

```
$ locate libcs.so.1
/opt/cloudshield/lib/libcs.so.1
```

ldd shows the following:

```
$ sudo ldd /opt/cloudshield/lib/libcs.so.1
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/opt/cloudshield/lib/libcs.so.1'
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff4fff000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7a0fd56000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000340ba00000)

$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libcs.so.1
```

Is it because of the kernel library linux-vdso.so.1?

```
Executable cannot find the library libcs.so.1:
[fpeter@localhost radius]$ ldd radius
    `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff634b4000)
    libconfd.so => /home/fpeter/trunk/thirdparty/tailf/confd/lib/libconfd.so (0x00007f5db20e6000)
    libcs.so.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000340c600000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000340c200000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000340ce00000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x0000003ba4a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000340ba00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000340be00000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x000000340d600000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `/opt/cloudshield/lib/` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, e.g.:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cloudshield/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

See also [How to build library ithoutsudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220762/how-to-build-library-without-sudo/31220826#31220826) or 
[shared libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).